# Sending emails from different domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, sendgrid-ruby, sendgrid-rails

We are currently running our ruby on rails application with SendGrid for sending emails. We have authenticated two subdomains in our SendGrid account:

1. test1.mydomain.com
2. test2.mydomain.com

Currently the default domain for sending emails is `test1.mydomain.com` which is configured in SendGrid.

But we want to send few emails from the subdomain `test2.mydomain.com` and others from `test1.mydomain.com`. Is it possible to send emails from different domains from a ruby on rails application?

Answer (score 0):

One part is to set up the MX and other DNS-based verifications for both domains. Sendgrid documentation will help you there if needed: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/

Then, in your mailer, you can set up a "from" address, which will appear as the sender.

If usually you would configure it once (in `config/environment/production.rb`) as

```rb
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

you can also set it up for each mailer class

```rb
class MyAlternativeMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "from@altdomain.example.com"

  def altmessage
  end
end
```